# Proper pattern or methodology to traverse data and dynamically construct objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jaxb

I'm looking for potentially some design pattern advice regarding object traversal to dynamically construct objects based on the data being presented.

Below, I am manually constructing this object. Initially, the root node is a `BinaryLogicOpType` but *could* be a different object based on the `rootNodeType`.

My question is.. I need to dynamically construct these objects of differing types based on the string data in my lists. What is the best route in doing so?

I'm willing to refine this questions if it's confusing.

```
String rootNodeType = fN.type;

BinaryLogicOpType _blop = new BinaryLogicOpType();
JAXBElement<BinaryLogicOpType> root = constructRootElement(_blop, factory, rootNodeType);

/** LETS CREATE THE FIRST CHILD ELEMENT */
BinaryComparisonOpType attrName1GTEFive = new BinaryComparisonOpType();
_blop.getOps().add(factory.createPropertyIsEqualTo(attrName1GTEFive));

JAXBElement<String> attr1Property = factory.createValueReference(fN.nodes.get(0).getProperty());
LiteralType attr1ValueLiteral = new LiteralType();
attr1ValueLiteral.getContent().add(fN.nodes.get(0).getValue());

JAXBElement<LiteralType> attr1Value = factory.createLiteral(attr1ValueLiteral);

attrName1GTEFive.getExpression().add(attr1Property);
attrName1GTEFive.getExpression().add(attr1Value);
```

## Sample JSON

```
{
  "type": "AND",
  "filters": [
    {
      "type": "=",
      "value": "exampleid",
      "property": "id"
    },
    {
      "type": "ILIKE",
      "value": "*",
      "property": "metacard-tags"
    },
    {
      "type": "OR",
      "filters": [
        {
          "type": ">=",
          "value": null,
          "property": "benumber"
        },
        {
          "type": "ILIKE",
          "value": "redshirts",
          "property": "title",
          "isCaseSensitive": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

## Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><fes:Filter xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
  <fes:Or>
    <fes:PropertyIsLessThan matchAction="ANY" matchCase="false">
      <fes:ValueReference>name</fes:ValueReference>
      <fes:Function name="sub">
        <fes:Literal>my-id</fes:Literal>
      </fes:Function>
    </fes:PropertyIsLessThan>
    <fes:And>
      <fes:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo matchAction="ANY" matchCase="false">
        <fes:ValueReference>attName</fes:ValueReference>
        <fes:Literal>5</fes:Literal>
      </fes:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
      <fes:PropertyIsLike escapeChar="\" matchCase="false" singleChar="?" wildCard="*">
        <fes:ValueReference>title</fes:ValueReference>
        <fes:Literal>greetings</fes:Literal>
      </fes:PropertyIsLike>
      <fes:PropertyIsEqual>
        <fes:ValueReference>be_number</fes:ValueReference>
        <fes:Function>
            <fes:Parameter>null</fes:Parameter>
            <fes:Parameter>null</fes:Parameter>
        </fes:Function> 
      </fes:PropertyIsEqual>
    </fes:And>
  </fes:Or>
</fes:Filter>
```

Comment: Do you Mean the dynamically created object will have different task to perform?

Comment: if rootNodeType is a string of 'And', for example, it will be a BinaryLogicOpType.. But then, if it's a 'Function' it will be a FunctionType. The functionality may vary. I basically need to create a mapping from String values to class types to determine what objects I need to instantiate.

Comment: Try `Strategy` or `State Pattern` with factory. I would Suggest State pattern

Comment: This looks promising, I'll check into this, thanks!

Comment: Please post the sample JSON and sample XML you want to convert it to. It will be easier to discuss then.

Comment: @lexicore the json and XML don't match up completely, but above is the rough idea of what I need to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is really no easy solution, but I'm pretty sure it is possible to implement conversion in quite an elegant manner with OOP.

Essentially, you're dealing with [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s in both cases. And the their structures are not so different at all. So if you'd manage to implement conversion routine for each of the possible node types, you should be able to convert the whole AST.

First of all, I'd start by implementing a good Java model for your JSON structure. Classes like `AndExpression`, `ComparisonExpression`, `LikeExpression`, `OrExpression` etc. For inspiration, check the generated classes of the `Filter` schema. Good modelling is essential here.

Use poliformic deserialization so that you get the proper object structure after parsing Jackson. Now you "only" need to convert this structure into your JAXB structure.

The simplest would be to add conversion methods to your JSON model classes directly. I'd make them all implement an interface with a method like:

```
public Object convertToJAXB(ObjectFactory objectFactory);
```

In the case of "leaf" AST nodes like `ILIKE` you can just construct the appropriate object directly.
In the case of "composite" AST nodes like `AND` or `OR` you will need to call `convertToJAXB` on each of the `filters` and then do some more work by wrapping results into `JAXBElements`. You might need some `instanceof` checks here; it should be possible to come up with a more intelligent solution.